# mediaelement.js audio example working also in Firefox

Tags: mediaelement.js

In mediaelement.js 2.6.5, the supplied demo "mediaelementplayer-audio.html" file demonstrates how to use mediaelement.js with **audio only**. However, this demo works only in **Safari**. It **doesn't work in Firefox, Opera nor IE8**.

The audioplayer on **mediaelement.js.com does work** in all browsers I tried. I'm analyzing it now, but downloading the source and **serving it locally isn't working**. I have yet to find the difference.

**Anyone have a working example for audio only mediaelement.js?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flash doesn't work with local files unless you change your Flash security settings. Go to http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html and allow the directory you're working with.

Comment: I actually had done that previously, but didn't think of checking whether this was still the case. I suppose that on the way when switching between Firefox versions 3.0, 3.5, 4, 5, 6, 7,8,9 and 10 this setting was affected inadvertently. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen the same problem with Firefox 12 on Ubuntu (Mint). The player just doesn't work; it shows a black DIV with nothing in it.